# CSS element size after translateZ

Tags: html, css, parallax

i've discovered something recently.
I'm trying to achieve parallax with CSS acoording to this CODEpen
https://codepen.io/keithclark/pen/JycFw

I've got something like:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="parallax">
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.parent {
    perspective:1px;
}
.parallax {
    transform: translateZ(.35px) scale(.65);
}
```

And everything works fine - parallax is working. But i found out that .parallax element is not the size of a real one, for example when i want to hover it the box of element is elswhere.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jvj9tz61/1/

Comment: Can you provide fiddle?

Comment: After only `translateZ(.35px)` or `translateZ(.35px) scale(.65)`? If only `translateZ` then it is bound to happen because the element is moving closer to you eye and any item that moves closer to your eye will appear big.

Comment: Harry - yes i know, but how to avoid it?

Comment: Emirhan Özlen - here is the fiddle - check the image with the inspector and see that it's size don't match with what is displaying.

Comment: Sorry, forgot about fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jvj9tz61/1/

Comment: @user3267302 You can't avoid it. The element will be larger if you use perspective and translateZ unless you clip the image.

Comment: But this would not have any impact on the `:hover`. It should continue to work on the whole image.- [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jvj9tz61/2/).